# Why ViewPager on first page reset other pages data?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using `ViewPager` in my app. when I swipe to page 3 and change some things on this page (like writing texts in `EditText`) and come back to page 1 and then swipe to page 3 again; changes was reset (texts was cleared). why? and how can I prevent it?

I'm using this codes:

```
ViewPager tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.add_cost_pager);

        AddCostPagerAdapter adapter = new AddCostPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        tab.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AddCostPagerAdapter.class:

```
private class AddCostPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public AddCostPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new Page_1();

        case 1:
            return new page_2();

        case 2:
            return new page_3();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add more information or some code.

Comment: @Mr Mush codes added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

After this line of code :

```
ViewPager tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.add_cost_pager);
```

Add this :

```
tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```